# How to calculate the fitted values of out-of-sample predictions from conditional fixed-effects Poisson model?

Tags: panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model, poisson-regression, out-of-sample

I am trying to calculate fitted values from `xtpoisson` fixed effects on out-of-sample data. I know how to calculate fitted values for in-sample predictions (using the stata auto data), and the below code is what I use to transform the output from the post-estimation command "predict, xb". However, for out-of-sample predictions when the DV (price) is not known, how can these commands be adapted to make out of sample predictions? Or is there entirely different way to do it?

```
sysuse auto, clear
g id=rep78
drop if id==.
xtset id
xtpoisson price mpg, fe
predict double fitted, xb
gen double yhat=exp(fitted)
egen meany=mean(price) , by(id)
egen meanyhat=mean(yhat), by(id)
gen double exp_alpha=meany/meanyhat if meanyhat>0
replace yhat=yhat*exp_alpha if meanyhat>0
su price yhat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a panel FE Poisson model, the expected value is given by

$$E[y_{it} \vert x_{it}]=\exp(\alpha_i + x_{it}\beta)=\exp(\alpha_i) \cdot \exp(x_{it}\beta)$$

Unfortunately, the *time-invariant* fixed effects $\alpha_i$s are not estimated since they drop out of the likelihood function once you conditioned on the sum of the outcomes in the set (panel). They are a kind of nuisance parameter, but you do need them to calculate predictions. There are at least four solutions:

1. "back the FEs out" like you did above
2. fit an ordinary pooled Poisson with dummies for every panel (estimate the FEs)
3. fit the model, change $x$ to some counterfactual value like $x+1$, and predict using method (1) or (2)
4. fit a panel Poisson that recovers the FEs (like `ppmlhdfe` from SSC)

The second approach is very easy unless you have tons of panels and not enough computer. I will demonstrate (1), (2), and (4) below. Method (3) is useful when you are interested in counterfactuals in the past, rather than in the future (i.e, had I done X before rather than what if I do X in the future). (4) is a more modern way of fitting high-dimensional FE models.

If you want to extrapolate to some other group, where you lack any "estimates" of the FEs, you have to take a stand on what values to use in that prediction. You might use the in-sample mean or median $\hat \alpha_i$. Using zero is probably a bad idea.

In the example below, we have data on the weights of 48 pigs over 9 weeks, and we will extrapolate their weights in weeks 10-13.

Here's the output (with code at the very bottom):

```
. capture ssc install carryforward

. capture ssc install ppmlhdfe

. webuse pig, clear
(Longitudinal analysis of pig weights)

. replace weight = round(weight,1)
(210 real changes made)

. xtset id week, delta(1)
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  week, 1 to 9
                delta:  1 unit

. xtdescribe

      id:  1, 2, ..., 48                                     n =         48
    week:  1, 2, ..., 9                                      T =          9
           Delta(week) = 1 unit
           Span(week)  = 9 periods
           (id*week uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         9       9       9         9         9       9       9

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00  100.00 |  111111111
 ---------------------------+-----------
       48    100.00         |  XXXXXXXXX

. tsappend, add(4) // add 4 extra weeks to extrapolation

. xtpoisson weight c.week, fe nolog

Conditional fixed-effects Poisson regression    Number of obs     =        432
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =         48

                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          9
                                                              avg =        9.0
                                                              max =          9

                                                Wald chi2(1)      =    2142.21
Log likelihood  = -1079.9655                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      weight |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |   .1250631   .0027021    46.28   0.000     .1197672    .1303591
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. gen double yhat          = exp(_b[week]*week) // prediction as if FE alpha_i = 0 for all i

. egen meany           = mean(weight), by(id)

. egen meanyhat        = mean(yhat) if !missing(weight), by(id)
(192 missing values generated)

. bys id (week): carryforward meany meanyhat, replace
meany:  (0 real changes made)
meanyhat:  (192 real changes made)

. gen double exp_alpha = meany/meanyhat

. replace yhat = yhat*exp_alpha
(624 real changes made)

. sum weight yhat if !missing(weight)

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      weight |        432    50.64815    16.62236         20         88
        yhat |        432    50.64815    16.70314   24.89115     93.973

. qui poisson weight c.week i.id

. predict yhat_pooled
(option n assumed; predicted number of events)

. ppmlhdfe weight c.week, absorb(id) d(alpha_ppml) nolog
Converged in 5 iterations and 5 HDFE sub-iterations (tol = 1.0e-08)

HDFE PPML regression                              No. of obs      =        432
Absorbing 1 HDFE group                            Residual df     =        383
                                                  Wald chi2(1)    =    8194.19
Deviance             =  76.29381688               Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood =  -1270.94379               Pseudo R2       =     0.4793
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
      weight |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        week |   .1250631   .0013816    90.52   0.000     .1223553     .127771
       _cons |   3.250948   .0089411   363.60   0.000     3.233424    3.268472
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
-----------------------------------------------------+
 Absorbed FE | Categories  - Redundant  = Num. Coefs |
-------------+---------------------------------------|
          id |        48           0          48     |
-----------------------------------------------------+

. bys id (week): carryforward alpha_ppml, replace
alpha_ppml:  (192 real changes made)

. predict yhat_ppml
(option mu assumed; predicted mean of depvar)

. corr yhat*
(obs=624)

             |     yhat yhat_p~d yhat_p~l
-------------+---------------------------
        yhat |   1.0000
 yhat_pooled |   1.0000   1.0000
   yhat_ppml |   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000


. xtline yhat yhat_pooled yhat_ppml weight if inlist(id,1) ///
> , legend(label(1 "xtpoisson") label(2 "poisson") label(3 "ppmlhdfe") label(4 "Data") rows(1)) ///
> xlab(#12) lpattern(solid dash dash_dot solid) lwidth(thick thick thick thick) byopt(note(""))

. graph export "forecasts_and_actual_pig_weights.jpg", quality(90) replace
```

The graph for pig #1 looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, all three approaches make identical predictions, and I was able to predict counterfactual outcomes. Here time plays the role of price.

The `ppmlhdfe` and `poisson` model have an intercept, whereas `xtpoisson` does not, so exp_alpha = exp(alpha_ppml + _b[_cons]) = exp(_b[_cons] + _b[XXX.id]), where XXX is the id for that panel.

---

**Stata Code:**

```
cd "~/Desktop"
cls
capture ssc install carryforward
capture ssc install ppmlhdfe
webuse pig, clear
replace weight = round(weight,1)
xtset id week, delta(1)
xtdescribe
tsappend, add(4) // add 4 extra weeks to extrapolation
xtpoisson weight c.week, fe nolog
gen double yhat      = exp(_b[week]*week) // prediction as if FE alpha_i = 0 for all i
egen meany           = mean(weight), by(id)
egen meanyhat        = mean(yhat) if !missing(weight), by(id)
bys id (week): carryforward meany meanyhat, replace
gen double exp_alpha = meany/meanyhat
replace yhat = yhat*exp_alpha
sum weight yhat if !missing(weight)
qui poisson weight c.week i.id
predict yhat_pooled
ppmlhdfe weight c.week, absorb(id) d(alpha_ppml) nolog
bys id (week): carryforward alpha_ppml, replace
predict yhat_ppml
corr yhat*
xtline yhat yhat_pooled yhat_ppml weight if inlist(id,1) ///
, legend(label(1 "xtpoisson") label(2 "poisson") label(3 "ppmlhdfe") label(4 "Data") rows(1)) ///
xlab(#12) lpattern(solid dash dash_dot solid) lwidth(thick thick thick thick) byopt(note(""))
graph export "forecasts_and_actual_pig_weights.jpg", quality(90) replace
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy

Comment: @BryanE.Burke No need to thank me, but please select my response as the answer by clicking on the check mark if this resolved your problem.

Comment: Your answer is constent with what others have said. However, my minimum level of compentency at statistics sometime struggles with recognizing the brillance of others. Once I do my due diligency and discuss these solutions with other people on my team, I will get back to that check box. 

I was not aware of the purpose of the check box until you pointed it out.  It seems like you make a major contribution to stackexchange. It is much appreciated.